# Problem with MessageBox(es)

Tags: c#, wpf, refresh, messagebox

I am experiencing strange behavior using MessageBox(es) in a C#/WPF program.

Create a basic WPF application put some labels on it and a button.

Here is the code of the button click

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result;
        do
        {

            result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Please Click here under", "TestBugMessageBox", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Information, MessageBoxResult.None);
            if (result.Equals(MessageBoxResult.OK))
            {
                result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Is it the first time you see it ?", "TestBugMessageBox", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.None);
            }
        } while (result.Equals(MessageBoxResult.Yes));
    }
```

Then Place the windows on the center of the screen ( in order for the MessageBox to cover some labels )

Click yes three times, and no the last time and you will see the problem (I hope):

The message box stays shown on the app.

Could you let me know what's wrong with it?

Comment: I actually did fire up Visual Studio to compile this, and I can't tell what the problem is. So it looks like you're going to have to tell us. No combination of clicks can make it stay on the screen.

Comment: Fine for me too.  Can you give us a hint?

Comment: It is likely that your problem is environmental - it could be to do with graphics card, .NET version, Windows version or Windows configuration.  You'll need to post more info about what the actual problem is because it is working for everyone else.

Comment: @greg S. that is probably highly likely. Upgrade video driver before anything else.

Comment: Why would this be a video driver problem? It's far more likely there's other code or settings in your application that are affecting this than the graphics card. Create a new, blank project and paste your code there like we did.

Comment: im also getting the same problem. if you refresh the window it will go. its just showing the image of the messagebox

Comment: Thanks a lot from what you seems to say this problem comes from my PC only. I will check more about your suggestion

Comment: I am indeed using a multimonitor system but I just use one.I tried with Cancel value and no value with the same effect.

Comment: I tried on an other PC on a totally different environment (Japanese Windows PC) and I got the same behavior. After a combination of quick OK, Yes, OK and No some MessageBox windows graph does not disappear unless I resize the main windows. I am using .Net Framework 4.0 and visual C# express 2010 under XP. Looks strange to me

Comment: @Spo: I tried this on both Windows 7 and XP and problem only occurs on XP

Comment: @Cody Gray: It's called the process of elimination dude. Removing assumptions from the problem domain, resolves the issue faster.

Comment: @Spo, also have you tried substituting .Equals method for == operator?

Comment: @Cody Gray: WPF is very reliant on the graphics hardware - most rendering problems I've had with WPF turned out to be hardware specific.

Comment: @Anonymous Type: Ironically, my previous comment also described a process of elimination. The difference is "upgrade your video driver" isn't all that helpful. What if there isn't an upgrade? What if the same problem is visible on multiple PCs? It's probably not the video card. Starting over with a blank project is an even quicker way to remove an even larger number of unknowns.

Comment: @Greg Sansom: I don't think this qualifies as a "rendering problem". Although I agree that WPF is comparably more reliant on the graphics hardware than say WinForms, I wasn't questioning whether the problem could *possibly* be related to the graphics card. Only observing that I don't think it is the *most likely* scenario.

Comment: This is also not reproducible on a clean Windows XP virtual machine. You can't get much worse graphics drivers than that. I even tried 16-bit color mode.

Comment: @Cody, ok fair point. I was simply coming from the point of view that its better to eliminate hardware issues whenever dealing with a graphics related issue from the problem domain before looking at software config issues. But if you can't reproduce on a clean XP machine, I'd say its environmental.

Comment: Ok before we go further your missing some information.
For instance, are you using multiple monitors?

I note your using MessageBoxResult.None
have you tested with the other values?

have you tried using .ShowDialog() method for modal operation? If so was the result different?

UPDATE:
Does it reproduce with .NET 3.5 on XP? i.e. can it be isolated to WPF .Net 4 
or does this happen with all versions of WPF?

Can you reproduce with a winforms project?

Answer (score 1):

Are you debugging and staying on a breakpoint in the do..while loop?
If answer is "yes", you have to remove breakpoints: wpf can't redraw the surface of your window if you lock a cycle on main thread.

EDIT:
Even debugging and breakpointing the do..while I wasn't able to reproduce described behaviour.
The issue I talked about is only when stopping the UI thread (eg. when overriding Measure || Arrange methods and debugging them), not the main thread. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this on a Windows 7 64-bit multi monitor system in Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0 C#/WPF and it ran fine for me.

The only difference is my MessageBox.Show does not take in the 'this' object.

Are you using System.Windows.MessageBox?

Maybe it just needs a Windows update and/or a reinstall of the .NET framework.